# error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401

Tags: bash, git, azure, shell

### I try to do a commit in my repository but I can't solve this problem, any idea?

```
#!/bin/bash 

mkdir target
cd target

git clone https://oauth2:${GIT_TOKEN}@dev.azure.com/tufia/IPD006/_git/wiki-Release-status

cd wiki-Release-status/publish
cp -r  ../../../publish .
ls -al
cd ..


git config  user.email "p.example.aas@tufia.onmicrosoft.com"
git config  user.name "p.example.s"
git add ./publish 
git commit -m "31/05/2019"
echo "PUSHING"
git push origin master -f
```

Cloning into 'wiki-Release-status'...

total 16

drwxr-xr-x 3 AgentPoolAdmin1 AgentPoolAdmin1 4096 May 31 08:50 .

drwxr-xr-x 4 AgentPoolAdmin1 AgentPoolAdmin1 4096 May 31 08:50 ..

-rw-r--r-- 1 AgentPoolAdmin1 AgentPoolAdmin1  194 May 31 08:50 ReleaseVersion.md

drwxr-xr-x 2 AgentPoolAdmin1 AgentPoolAdmin1 4096 May 31 08:50 publish
[master 7264d67] 31/05/2019

PUSHING

error: RPC failed; HTTP 401 curl 22 The requested URL returned error: 401

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Everything up-to-date